# How do I set 1st row value from sql in ssrs report?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on SSRS report.

There are two main fields `CurrentMV` and `PreviousMV` both are having there different formulas but I'm taking PreviousMV as a value of CurrentMV using `=Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))`

Now How can I set 1st field only from sql and rest of other as it is coming from expression?

Because of I'm using `Previous function` 1st value is always coming null :(

I have the field in reporting proc which can give me the values but How can I set both 1st values as well as `Previous function` ?

[image]

Using `Ian` posts in answer But ,
I want to display only `1st field` from `Sum(Fields!PreviousMV.Value)` 
and all preceding values by using `Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))`

I tried like following and getting syntax error:

```
=First(Sum(Fields!PreviousMV.Value)) ,Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly check for NULL values:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value)))
    , Sum(Fields!PreviousMV.Value)
    , Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value)))
```

Since there are no `Previous` groups for the first group, this will return NULL for the first group, and hence the above expression will work for you.

Here is a simple report that uses the expression.

Data:

[image]

Report:

[image]

The expression value is the one above.

Result:

[image]

You can see it's picking up the values as intended.

Comment: Thanks for above answer but If I only need to show 1st row from sql field without IF condition? 
and i.e also sum(field.previousMV)
please correct me in syntax

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question.. It seems like you want to display a different value based on whether `Previous` is `NULL`, so `IIf` seems a good way to do this.

Comment: No, I will never get a any value `(currentmv or previousmv) to NULL`
that is the problem I `can't` use `IF condition to check NULL`

I simply want to show 1st value from `SUM(previousMV)` and other preceeding from `Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))`
Please help thanks

Comment: The `Previous` function will *always* return NULL for the first group, as by definition there are no previous values to return. I've added an example showing the expression being used and working as intended.